# When and where to add the go statement in DolphinDB?

Tags: parsing, dolphindb

A `go` statement splits a script into two blocks. Variables registered in the first block can only be referenced and parsed in the second block after DolphinDB parses and executes the first block. How to identify the dynamically registered variables or functions and add the `go` statement in the right place?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, the `go` statement can be used when a variable or function, as an internal object of certain functions, can only be registered or undefined after the execution of these functions and may be referenced in the subsequent code, such as a shared table registered with the `share` function, an object registered with the `runScript` function, and a variable undefined with the `undef` function.

In most cases, a function passes a script or object as a string. The variable or function defined in the script or object can only be registered after the execution. For example, in the script `share(t, st)`, the parameter st is passed as a string and referenced in the subsequent code. Without the `go` statement, an error would occur since the object "st" has not been generated before execution. The script can be rewritten as `share t as st`. In this way, DolphinDB directly registers st as a variable during parsing so there is no need to add the `go` statement. For detailed examples of the go statement, please refer to go — DolphinDB 2.0 documentation.

Some scripting languages execute code line by line. Some high level languages execute code step by step. For example, a C++ program follows the compiling - linking - executing process.By combining the benefits of both, DolphinDB can identify errors during parsing, avoiding the scenario where errors, such as syntax issues and mismatched parameters, are discovered after lengthy script execution. Moreover, most languages use the conventional dictionary approach to associate variable names with the corresponding values. DolphinDB associates each variable with an ID during parsing and uses these IDs to access variable values during execution, which saves time for searching and improves the execution speed.